# Multicast onBackpressureBuffer Sink does not accept new Subs after dispose

Tags: project-reactor, subscription, dispose, sink

When I unsubscribe the last Sub and sub again, I expect the Sink/Flux to work or throw an Exception.

See my Testcode:

```
void playground() {
        Sinks.Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
        var disposer = sink.asFlux().subscribe(s -> System.out.println("1: "+s));
        System.out.println("CurrentSubs:" + sink.currentSubscriberCount());
        sink.tryEmitNext("Test1");
        var disposer2 = sink.asFlux().subscribe(s -> System.out.println("2: "+s));
        System.out.println("CurrentSubs:" + sink.currentSubscriberCount());
        sink.tryEmitNext("Test2");
        disposer.dispose();
        System.out.println("CurrentSubs:" + sink.currentSubscriberCount());
        sink.tryEmitNext("Test3");
        disposer2.dispose();
        System.out.println("CurrentSubs:" + sink.currentSubscriberCount());
        var disposer3 = sink.asFlux().subscribe(s -> System.out.println("3: "+s));
        System.out.println("CurrentSubs:" + sink.currentSubscriberCount());
        sink.tryEmitNext("Test4");
        disposer3.dispose();
        System.out.println("CurrentSubs:" + sink.currentSubscriberCount());
    }
```

And the Output:

```
1: Test1
CurrentSubs:2
1: Test2
2: Test2
CurrentSubs:1
2: Test3
CurrentSubs:0
CurrentSubs:0
CurrentSubs:0
```

This behaviour seems weird to me, I would at least expect an Exception when I try to sub again and fail.

Is there any reason behind this behaviour.

Comment: I opened a [bug report](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/3715) about this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is kind of a gray area and not documented well. The `onBackpressureBuffer()` `Sinks.Many` does by default `autoCancel`, so once the subscriber count drops to zero, the operator stops emitting values to new subscribers.
Since it is now in cancelled state, all new subscriptions will immediately complete without emitting a value right upon subscription. Therefore the following is true

```
assert disposer3.isDisposed();
```

In reactor, cancellation per se is not an error. Therefore, it is kind of OKish when you don't get an exception when subscribing to an `autoCancelled` `Sinks.Many`.

What bothers me more is that even though the `Sink` was `autoCancel`ed, it still accepts emissions via `tryEmitNext`. So following is `true` even after the `autoCancel`lation took place.

```
assert sink.tryEmitNext("Test4").isSuccess();
```

So the API will let you keep emitting values even though the `Sink` is pretty much dead. Only after you fill the internal `queue` in the `Sink` you get `EmitResult.FAIL_OVERFLOW` result. The `Sink` "knew" it has been `autoCancel`ed and will still let you emit values which the new subscribers will never see... I can imagine a scenario where this could lead to an intermittent memory leak or such.

Anyway, if you want your example to work more intuitively just disable the `autoCancel` behavior of  `onBackpressureBuffer()` like so

```
Sinks.Many<String> sink = Sinks
    .many()
    .multicast()
    .onBackpressureBuffer(Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE, false);
```