# Sinks.Many silently becomes useless after subscriber count reaches 0 the first time

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, spring-webflux, project-reactor

If I make a `Sinks.Many` instance:

```
Sinks.Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
```

Then in a different thread (T1), I subscribe to its `Flux`:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    sink.asFlux().take(5).subscribe(
        m -> System.out.println("T1: " + m),  //onNext
        System.out::println,                  //onError
        () -> System.out.println("T1 DONE")); //onComplete
})
.start();
```

And emit some elements in the "main" thread:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sink.tryEmitNext(i);
    Thread.sleep(500);
}

//Verify that 0 subscribers are left at this point
System.out.println("Subscribers: " + sink.currentSubscriberCount());
```

I see T1 printing 0-4 and "DONE" as expected, but the sink becomes useless at this point — all further subscriptions instantly complete for some reason, and emissions no longer do anything observable.

E.g. if I try subscribing and emitting again:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    sink.asFlux().take(5).subscribe(
        m -> System.out.println("T2: " + m),  //onNext
        System.out::println,                  //onError
        () -> System.out.println("T2 DONE")); //onComplete
})
.start();
    
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Sinks.EmitResult emitResult = sink.tryEmitNext(i);
    if (emitResult.isFailure()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(); //Never happens
    }
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

T2 instantly prints "T2 DONE" because the `Flux` is seemingly complete, yet each subsequent `sink.tryEmitNext` is still successful (`isSuccessful() == true`).

I am clearly failing to understand how `Sinks.many().multicast()` is supposed to work because this behavior makes no sense to me. What completed the `Flux` when `(try)EmitComplete` was never called? Why is the sink still emitting successfully if nothing can subscribe to it? It is stuck in limbo where it's both complete and not.

What am I missing? Should I be using different constructs (see below) to have an endless sink that permits subscribers to come and go as they please?

If I instead define my sink as:

```
//0 because I don't actually want any replay
Sinks.Many<Integer> sink = Sinks.many().replay().limit(Duration.ZERO);
```

I get the result I expect — T2 also gets its 5 elements.

Comment: `tryEmitNext` does **not** throw any exception on failure. You have to check on its return status to verify if it failed or succeed. That being said, if `tryEmitNext` on non-replayable sink returns `EmitResult.OK` when no subscriber is present, then I think there is a bug in the library.

Comment: @amanin I am aware of this, and yes, emitting does really succeed. But I'm more confused by the ghostly completed `Flux` (that no one completed) than by the later successful emissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is an expected behavior with `onBackpressureBuffer()` which enables `autoCancel` by default (although not documented in the method doc itself), completing the sink once all subscribers have unsubscribed.

To disable it, use the overload: `onBackpressureBuffer(int bufferSize, boolean autoCancel)`.

Example:

```
Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer(Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE, false);
```

Similar posts:

- [Multicast onBackpressureBuffer Sink does not accept new Subs after dispose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76422519/multicast-onbackpressurebuffer-sink-does-not-accept-new-subs-after-dispose)
- [Why is Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer() completing after one of the subscribers cancels the subscription and how to avoid it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66671636/why-is-sinks-many-multicast-onbackpressurebuffer-completing-after-one-of-t)

Comment: Ah, thanks! That mostly explains it. But. Why does publishing on a completed sink still succeed? That *must* be a bug, right?

Comment: It looks like a bug indeed. Completing it manually will have the desired effect of unsuccessful emissions but when this `autoCancel` happens it stills "succeeds" to emit but no subscriber gets it since the sink got effectively completed.

Comment: I opened the [issue 3715](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/3715) on reactor-core.